# Multiple subdir sites protection and authentication (Not .htpasswd)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, authentication, webserver

I want to protect multiple sites within sub directories. The best would be an easy way to manage users and what sites they can access, and display a nice login site.
i.e:
Sites/mysite1
Sites/mysite2

Please feel free to ask questions. I know there probably are tons of solutions.

Comment: What's wrong with `.htpasswd`?

Comment: Good question! I need a better way to view, add, edit and delete users. Controll what sites they can access, and it would be good to show an html for instead of the browser popup that .htpasswd triggers. The setup is meant for deploying sites in progress so that clients and co-workers can access them.

If you know of a **crud** solution for .htpasswd that would be awesome as well!